# Separate old files with date information stored in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, windows-explorer, vba

I have approximately 2000 files, of which I need to separate any files before a specific date (say, 2015).

These are currently separated into subfolders for each categories of file (Say, projecttype1, projecttype2) and I have a .txt file for each folder with the full file name listed alphabetically.

The files do not have "Date Modified" information, as these were extracted from a corrupt database file, and hence read as being created/modified on today's date

As in Explorer: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJN30.png]

From the database I recovered the file list, which includes the date created/date modified timestamps

As in Excel: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaiHX.png]

The files in explorer have an extension of .rap, and a ~30 character limit on the names, so I'm certain I can partially match these up with the data on the spreadsheet, however I've been struggling to do.

I'm looking to ideally parse the data into a date range (say pre/post 2015) as I'm trying to avoid rebuilding the .blb database with all the old data from 2006-2015.

I've tried a few different internal tools, but short of manually combing through the recovered files I can't think of a way of doing so - would the sheet with the names/dates, paired with the individual files be enough to sort and move the data?